# how to add role with same name and some customize column using asp.net identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

```
IdentityResult result = _roleManager.Create(new Role("TestRole", 6, "Test Role Description"));    
db.Roles.Add(new Role() { 
             Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
             Name = "TestRole", companyId = 6, 
             description = "Test Role Description"});
db.SaveChanges();
```

when i try to do it apart from RoleManager it shows entity validation error.

Comment: Name column of table AspNetRoles has unique index constraint, so you can not add a role with same. Thats probably the validation error you are getting

Comment: Can we remove it by code first?

Comment: Show us the error message please

Comment: Error is that "RoleName is already taken."
but i want to add with same name.

Comment: Why do you want to have 2 "TestRole", a role is defined by it's name, it must be unique

Answer (score 2):

I've met the same issue .

First:
I changed Role Name Index by the code in :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
            rolesTable.Property(x => x.Name)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("RoleNameIndex") { IsUnique = false }));
}
```

when i save the roles twice like this:

```
 db.roles.add(role);
 db.savechanges();
 db.roles.add(role2);//role.name == role2.name && role.companyid != role2.companyid
 db.savechanges();
```

the code show error but it works fine this way:

```
     db.roles.add(role);
     db.roles.add(role2);//role.name == role2.name && role.companyid != role2.companyid
     db.savechanges();
```

it is not very good so.

Last I recommend:
      use unique role name with a companyid in it like this:

```
 AnyRoleName#CompanyId//example:'Admin#1'
```

Hope it's helpful.